# How to modify a class's data tag inside onClickListener?

Tags: android

Please help me with this, i never ever understanded how things work inside onClickListener, so:

Got my own class:

```
public class ItemFrame extends LinearLayout{

     int item_id;

     public ItemFrame(Context context){
        super(context);
     }

     public int getItem_id() {
        return item_id;
     }

    public void setItem_id(int item_id) {
        this.item_id = item_id;
     }
}
```

I initalize one and add an onClickListener:

```
ItemFrame myItemFrame = new ItemFrame(this);

myItemFrame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){

                                   //ERROR HERE:
                                   //Cannot refer to a non-final variable myItemFrame inside an inner class 
                                   //defined in a different method
                                   //Quick fix: Change modifier of 'myItemFrame' to final.
                    myItemFrame.setItemId(100);
                }


            });
```

So... My question is:
How can i set a data tag of my class, inside the onClickListener???
If i change it to final as Eclipse says, i cant modify it since it is **final**. 
Does it make any sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OnClickListener that you created is an anonymous inner class and can only refer to final values.

Simply change:

```
ItemFrame myItemFrame = new ItemFrame(this);
```

to be:

```
final ItemFrame myItemFrame = new ItemFrame(this);
```

You can still modify the ItemFrame object that you created.  You just can't reassign a new one to the myItemFrame variable.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to implement your code, have a look at it.

```
public class ItemFrame extends LinearLayout implements OnClickListener
{
     int item_id;

     public ItemFrame(Context context)
     {
        super(context);
     }

     public int getItem_id() 
     {
        return item_id;
     }

    public void setItem_id(int item_id) 
    {
        this.item_id = item_id;
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       setItemId(100);
    }
}
```